# XML - Как сделать блок текста

Tags: android, xml

Необходимо сделать блок-правил приложения со скроллингом. Как это лучше осуществить через TextView или TextEdit и если можно пример.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, обвернуть твой `TextView` во `ScrollView` либо `NestedScrollView`.
И высоту (`height`) у `TextView` поставить `wrap-content`.
Таким образом, у тебя будет скроллинг, а высота блока текста будет по содержимому.